# Eliminar dado selecionado do array

Tags: javascript

Na minha função eu insiro um dado informado em um array e em uma box para visualização do usuário. Mas caso ele queira retirar essa informação, ele seleciona ela e é retirada através da function! Porém caso ele informar a mesma informação novamente, ela da erro informando que já existe!

Ex:

```
variaveis na function
         w_Cont_Qtde = 1;
         w_Qtde_Peri = $arr_w_param[10]; --> $arr_w_param[10] é a quantidade informada em uma tela anterior (ex: 5 / 10 / ...) 
         v_patr = new Array (w_Qtde_Peri);
```

**Insere os dados**

```
function move(Origem, Destino)
{   
   var w_valor = Origem.value;  
 if (w_Cont_Qtde <=  w_Qtde_Peri)
    {        
    if ((v_patr.indexOf(w_valor) == -1) && (w_valor != ""))
       {
        var opt = document.createElement("option"); 
        opt.text = w_valor ;
        opt.value = w_valor ;
        Destino.options.add(opt);
        v_patr[w_Cont_Qtde]= w_valor;
        w_Cont_Qtde = w_Cont_Qtde +1;
        return true;
       }       
    else
        {   
        alert("Patrimônio OU Serial já existe OU não é válido!");
        return true;    
        }
   }
 alert("Quantidade informada ja Incluida !!!");
return true; 
}
```

**Retira os dados (só está eliminando da box)**

```
function tira(Destino) 
{
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < Destino.options.length; i++)
    { 
        if (Destino.options[i].selected && Destino.options[i].value != "")
        {
            w_valor=Destino.options[i].value;
            w_Cont_Qtde = w_Cont_Qtde - 1;
            Destino.remove(Destino.selectedIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Meu problema é: "Eliminar o dado selecionado do array também, pois da box ele já elimina."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você pode remover itens de um array em javascript utilizando o [método splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp), você informa no primeiro parametro o índice do item e no segundo parametro a quantidade de itens a remover.

---

Editado (Exemplo de Utilização)

```
meuArray.splice(meuArray.indexOf(meuValor), 1);
```

ou seja, ele irá pegar o índice do item a remover do array e irá passar no primeiro parâmetro, e ele irá remover 1 item após este índice (2º parâmetro)

Comment: da mais preferência para a documentação do mozilla dev https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Obrigado Willian, para as futuras respostas irei utilizar a documentação da Mozilla.

Comment: @dennis90 se fosse para aplicar seria como?